# why doesn't mui dialog close on button click?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, dialog

In my React project I have a dialog that opens full screen but does not close when clicking on the close icon button.

The component opening the Dialog :

```
interface IContentCardProps {
  content: IContentProps;
}

const ContentCard = ({ content }: IContentCardProps) => {
  const { user } = useUser();
  const [open, setOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);

  return (
    <Box
      p={2}
      height="300px"
      maxWidth="250px"
      display="flex"
      flexDirection="column"
      justifyContent="space-between"
      border={`1px solid ${blue.main}`}
      sx={{
        cursor: "pointer",
        ":hover": { boxShadow: `0px 0px 3px 1px ${blue.main}` },
      }}
      onClick={() => setOpen(true)}
    >
      <Typography
        variant="body1"
        gutterBottom
        fontWeight={700}
        color={blue.main}
      >
        {content?.title}
      </Typography>
      <Typography
        variant="caption"
        marginBottom={1}
        lineHeight={1.6}
        textOverflow="ellipsis"
        display="-webkit-box "
        overflow="hidden"
        sx={{ WebkitLineClamp: 8, WebkitBoxOrient: "vertical" }}
      >
        {content?.description}
      </Typography>
      <Box pt={1} display="flex" alignItems="center" borderTop={`1px solid ${grey.extraLight}`}>
        <SvgIcon component={AccessTimeOutlinedIcon} sx={{ mr: 1 }} />
        <Typography variant="caption" fontWeight={700}>
          <span>{content?.duration}</span> min
        </Typography>
      </Box>
      <ContentDialog open={open} setOpen={setOpen} />
    </Box>
  );
};

export default ContentCard;
```

The dialog component :

```
const Transition = forwardRef(function Transition(
  props: TransitionProps & {
    children: React.ReactElement;
  },
  ref: React.Ref<unknown>,
) {
  return <Slide direction="left" ref={ref} {...props} />;
});

interface IContentDialogProps {
  open: boolean;
  setOpen: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}

const ContentDialog = ({ open, setOpen }: IContentDialogProps) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Dialog fullScreen open={open} onClose={() => setOpen(false)} TransitionComponent={Transition}>
        <AppBar sx={{ position: "relative", backgroundColor: blue.main }}>
          <Toolbar>
            <IconButton edge="start" color="inherit" onClick={() => setOpen(false)} aria-label="close">
              <CloseIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <Box> content</Box>
      </Dialog>
    </>
  );
};
```

SetOpen does not seem to work on the Dialog and I don't know why... 
If anyone has an idea that would be great !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking the close button triggers a click event, which can also bubble up and inadvertently trigger a click event on the parent element. This results in the execution of the `onClick={() => setOpen(true)}` function on the  element within `ContentCard`. To prevent this, you can use `stopPropagation` on the close button's click event. Here's how:

```js
onClick={(e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  setOpen(false);
}}
```

Additionally, because you're mainly closing the dialog in `ContentDialog`, you can create that function in `ContentCard`. Then, you can pass that instead of `setState` function.

[image: Edit focused-noether-74jxx5]

If you prefer not to use `stopPropagation`, you can simply place the `ContentDialog` outside the `Box` element. This way, the dialog won't be a direct child of the box element anymore. Here's how you can do it:

```js
function ContentCard({ content }) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const onClose = (e) => setOpen(false);

  return (
    <>
      <Box></Box>
      <ContentDialog open={open} onClose={onClose} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I created a function in the first place and passed it to the dialog instead of setState but it didn't work.
I added stopPropagation function and now the dialog finally closes.

Comment: @FlorieAnstett I also added another way to fix this if you prefer.